# Problem: Group BY clause showing results previously filtered out by where clause

Tags: sql

I have something like this

`select A, B, C 

from tableA 

where A = '123' 

group by B`

and the results include entries whose A is not '123'. Why is this not the results I expected it to be?

thanks

database has 16k entries

actual result (7k entries): a mixture of entries with A='123' and A='other'

expected results (5k entries): all entries with A='123'

Comment: Can you give an example of concrete values? Those within the tables, those returned from the query, and those which are desired.

Comment: How is that possible? You must use some aggregate functions to the values, that are not grouped by: `SELECT aggregate(A), B, SUM(C) WHERE a = '123' GROUP BY B`

Comment: please could you post your actual code? As it stands, that query can **only** return A = 123 - if you are seeing other values, your code must be significantly different to that posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will not work as A and C are not inside group by condition. For C you have to use Min, Max, Avg, Count,... aggregate functions, while for A you can use either aggregate function or diretly value of A something like:

```
Select Max(A) as A, B, Max(C) as C 
From Table
Where A='123'
Group by B
```

Or

```
Select '123' as A, B, Max(C) as C 
From Table
Where A='123'
Group by B
```